# Plugging unused yet unremovable 3/4" copper pipe

Tags: plumbing, pipe

I retired some 3/4" copper pipe but am not in a position to remove it because it would require demolition I don't want to do. The cut was made flush with the floor in my utility room. The pipe goes down from there. I pumped most residue water out, at least none is near the surface. What can I use to plug this hole (and should I)? I was thinking to maybe stuff some plumbers putty inside and then vinyl speckling on top to make it look like the surrounding tile.

[image]

Comment: Do you have or can get a replacement tile?  Can cut pipe with an internal pipe cutter or small dremal cutting/grinding wheel below the floor level.

Comment: It doesn't need to look pretty, I am mostly concerned with having an open pipe that might have some residue water in it can be toxic

Comment: Something like a rubber wine cork/stopper.  Think stuff like putty be hard to stop going down too far unless there was something to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plug ( may be a "Cleanout" plug) that comes in many sizes. It is rubber stopper with a bolt in the center. When the bolt is tightened, it expands the rubber to give a tight fit. It is removable.

Comment: All the cleanout plugs I was able to find on the interwebs were bigger than 3/4" copper

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't stuff any non-plumbing item into the pipe! Water will find a way to seep out the tiniest of openings. Or your house water pressure would blow out whatever you stuff in there. And clean out plugs described above are meant to be temporary. I would open the hole up more so i could insert a shark bite end plug in the appropriate size (1/2" or 3/4). Debur the cut and sand the end of the pipe with emery cloth first.You may have to cut the pipe so that the top of the shark bite plug is below the underside of the tile. Replace the tile with another.

Comment: Per the OP’s description, there is no supply to the pipe. They just want to avoid having it collect standing water.

Comment: @RLH, yeah, I wish people would read...

Comment: My bad. When you're senile, you start reading and forget what was stated at the beginning by the time you get to the end.....LOL